# ASP.NET MVC SessionID reset on every request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is exhibiting some strange behavior...

Each page request gives me a new Session ID, I have tried everything that I can think of and its still not working.

The session is not empty, I am writing data to it on session start.

I have read the other questions on here and have checked:
 1. All requests and coming from and going to the same domain.
 2. The session is not empty.
 3. The session is not being abandoned anywhere in the code.

I have used fiddler to confirm that the server is giving a new session ID on every request.

I have also checked the value of Session.IsNewSession and this is TRUE.

I must be missing something - if you have any idea what it might be I would really appreciate the help!

Fiddler output:
[image: Fiddler screen shot 1]

[image: Fiddler screen shot 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a session cookie that is marked "secure", but are making requests through HTTP (insecure).  Either access your site through https, or change your session cookie to be non-secure.

[image]

Comment: Hi,
No, tried this in IE, Firefox and chrome.

Knocked up a test MVC app and tested it in the same browser as I had tested the main app in and it works - its something in the application... just cant find it!

Comment: Post screen shots of two consecutive fiddler requests.

Comment: Thats going to be a pain.. The development environment doesn't have internet access... might have to be screen shots as in actual pictures of my screen!

Comment: Then just make sure the client is actually sending the cookie back on the second request.  That's all that would indicate a possible client problem.  Although, considering you said it is happening in multiple browsers the likelyhood of that is fairly low (but not impossible).

Comment: Well that was a bit of a faf - managed to get the screenshots over to my internet connected laptop - added them to the question now.

Comment: I've just confirmed that its *unlikley* to be the server - I have checked the application running on IIS Express, Cassini (Both on windows 7 dev machine) and now have also tested it on IIS 8.5 on windows 2012.

Comment: The client isn't sending back the session cookie in your fiddler samples. I am guessing here that my original answer is correct, your clients are configured to disable all cookies (with some exceptions).  Your main app is probably an exception.

Comment: Am I missing something - is there something that the app could be sending to the client(s) to get this behaviour as I said Ive tried different applications with the same browers and they work! I must be missing something.

It doesnt help that this is an application that Ive inherited and... well lets just say the standard of the code is less than optimal!

Comment: Sort of.  It could be requesting a permanent cookie instead of a session based one (commonly used for "Remember Me" type logins).  You can configure browsers to ignore those, but your fiddler output doesn't show that it is doing that.  Please check the settings in one of the browsers to verify.  Under chrome it would be in settings, advanced settings, privacy, content settings, and make sure "Allow local data to be set (recommended)" is selected.

Comment: Yeah, thats all fine.
Checked FF and Chrome, IE is locked down by GP so cant be checked but as other .net apps with session state are working Im 99.9% sure that the browser isn't the issue.

Ill keep at it - thanks for the help.

Comment: Got it.  Your cookie is set to be secure, and you aren't requesting data from a secure site.  If you put your site up as a https site, then the session will stick, or change the cookie type from secure to insecure.

Comment: Seriously, thank you!
I've been going over fiddler and looking over code all day - looks like some one has modified the web.config and checked it it some time ago.. I've only just started trying to pull data out of the session so it the first time the issue has come up!

I'd not thought of it because the whole network is internal with no external access so we don't have SSL (whether rightly or wrongly!) so I've got so used to not bothering with it that I hadn't thought to check!!

Thanks again - its working now!

Tomorrow Ill check the TFS history and administer beatings as required!